# Editing Downloaded Document changes the document on sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

A document in workflow task list is being downloaded when I click on it. it what I expected.

But, when I change the downloaded document. It sync back and changes the document on sharepoint online list.

**How can I stop that sync on sharepoint online?**

Answer (score 0):

It might be  sync to SharePoint work space is enabled. To disable follow the below instructions.

Select the document library. Click Library Settings. Click Advanced Settings under the General Settings category. Under Offline Client Availability category, select No to prevent users from download the documents.